# How do I add items to a bi-directional one-to-many relationship in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Say I have the following classes Box and Item. Where a box contains many Items, and an Item can only be in one Box. An Item also knows what Box it is in.

```
public class Box
{ 
   public virtual int BoxID {get; set:}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual IList<Item> Items {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public virtual int ItemID {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Box ContainerBox {get; set;}
 }
```

The Fluent NHibernate mapping classes might look like this.

```
public class BoxMap:ClassMap<Box>
{
    Id(b=>b.BoxId);
    Map(b=>b.Name);
    HasMany(b => b.Items)
        .Inverse()
        .CascadeAll();
}

public class ItemMap:ClassMap<Item>
{
    Id(i=>i.ItemId);
    Map(i=>i.Name);
    References(i => i.ContainerBox );
}
```

In general this works, but it's not as robust as I would like, as you need to know how associate things correctly. For example the `Box.Items.Add()` method will add items to the Box, but not update their `ContainerBox` properties. Like wise setting the `Item.ContainerBox` property does not add the item to the box.

So I figured I'd make Box.Items and IEnumerable to get rid of the Add() method, and instead add my own AddItem() method that will also set the Item.ContainerBox property.

```
public class Box
{ 
   private List<Item> _Items = new List<Item>();
   public virtual int BoxID {get; set:}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items 
   {
       get{return _Items;}
       private set 
           {
               _Items.Clear();
               _Items.AddRange(value);
           }
   }

   public void AddItem(Item i)
   {
       if(i.ContainerBox != null) throw new Exception("Item is already in a box!");
       i.ContainerBox = this;
       _Items.Add(i);
   }
}
```

I'm new to NHibernate, but I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea. Because, when a Box is later persisted from the database `Box.Items` wont point at `_Items` but rather will be overridden to point at some other NHibernate specific proxy collection. So calling `Box.AddItem()` on the persisted box, I think, wont actually add a new Item to the Box.

What is the correct way to do this? I'd like to have a single way to add an Item to a Box which updates Box.Items and Item.ContainerBox regardless of whether the Box is new or persisted from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `_Items` to protected and set your fluent mapping to the `_Items` property and this will work just fine. I've used this technique in a number of ways.

Comment: What does the Fluent mapping look like? I'm not seeing how you put the protected member in a lambda expression.

Comment: Here's what I did which seems to work: HasMany(b => b.Items).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)

Comment: Also see this page http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Mapping_a_collection_that_uses_a_private_backing_field and this page http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties